# How do I add custom parameter hints to VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've added a custom snippet to VSCode, which is good for setting up a function with many arguments, but how can I make it so the parameter hints popup shows up later on when I click inside the function, so I can see which argument is which?

Specifically I want to add one for `ctx.drawImage(image, 57, 31, 16, 16, 40, 26, 16, 16);`, as it's impossible to remember the order of the arguments.

Comment: try `Ctrl+Space` or `Ctrl+Shift+Space`

Comment: ctrl+shift+space kinda works but i have to click a few times, I want it to just pop up when my cursor is inside the function, like it does for built in functions that it recognizes